# Sklearn Linear Regression seems to not fit the Data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'am trying to train a linear regression model from Sklearn. However, it seems that the resulting regression does not fit the data very well. I would've expected the regression to (approximately) have a slope of 30°, whereas this regression does not show a correlation at all (horizontal slope). Does anyone of you guys have an idea on how I can modify my model to have a more appropriate prediction?

[Data Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnEIG.png)

This is the corresponding code:

```
# Define x & y:
x = pd.DataFrame({'patientweight': df['patientweight']})                 
y = pd.DataFrame({'rate':          df['rate']})
                  
# Split Data into Train-/Test-Set:
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=0)

# Train the Linear Regression Model:
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(x_train, y_train)

# Predict the Test Set Results:
y_pred = lin_reg.predict(x_train)

# Plot the data:
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
plt.xlabel('Patientweight')
plt.ylabel('Rate')
plt.title('Cohort 1: Relation between Patientweight and Rate')
plt.xlim(0,200)
plt.ylim(0,4000)
plt.scatter(df['patientweight'], df['rate'], alpha=0.25)
plt.scatter(x_train, y_pred)`
```

Comment: did you try to remove the outliers , Linear regression is affected by it

Comment: Yep, that's probably it. Thanks!